# Data source name not found and no default driver specified in Azure Runbook

Tags: sql, pyodbc, azure-automation

I am trying to run this code in Azure Automation Runbook but always get the same error

```
cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER='+driver+';SERVER='+server+';PORT='+port+';
DATABASE='+database+';UID='+username+';PWD='+password+';Authentication=ActiveDirectoryPassword')
```

Error:

```
pyodbc.InterfaceError: ('IM002', u'[IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')
```

Comment: Which driver version did you use? If you are using `{ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server}`, please try `{ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server}`.

Comment: We are using `{ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server}`. We have also tried `{ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server}` and `{SQL Server Native Client 11.0}'`but get the same error.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use `pyodbc` module to connect Azure sql database, the running environment should have Microsoft ODBC Driver for SQL Server. If it does not have the driver, you will get the error. For more details, please refer to the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/python/pyodbc/step-1-configure-development-environment-for-pyodbc-python-development?view=sql-server-ver15#windows). But Azure automation sandbox does not have the driver.

According to the situation, I suggest you host the script on Azure function.

For example(I host the script on Azure HTTP trigger function)

My code

```
async def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.')
    
    server = 'jimtestsql.database.windows.net'
    database = 'test'
    username = 'jim@hanxia.onmicrosoft.com'
    password = 'Wdsr199545#'
    driver= '{ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server}'
    cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER='+driver+';SERVER='+server+';PORT=1433;DATABASE='+database+';UID='+username+';PWD='+ password+';Authentication=ActiveDirectoryPassword')
    cursor = cnxn.cursor()
    cursor.execute("SELECT Top(1) * FROM [dbo].[StarWars]")
    row = cursor.fetchone()

    return func.HttpResponse(str(row[0]) + " " + str(row[1]))
```

[image]